# Loading dependencies only it's needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-maps-api-3

How the best way to load a dependecy of angularjs only when it's needed?

There is some built-in function that can inject the dependency when is needed?

The real problem is that the [GoogleMapsAPIs counts the load os static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#maps-credits), and the [libary to show the maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) I use should be declared in the angular module.

How can I remove the `google-maps` from module definition and only loads on the controller I need.

Comment: You mean something like that? http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/09/30/requirejs-angularjs-dependency-injection/ 

"Asynchronous Module Definition Pattern
The AMD pattern allows developer to

Define discrete JS modules…modules that may have 1..n external dependencies for other modules, and
Load these modules asynchronously (e.g. at some later time)"

Comment: using your conditions and business flow you can do this

Comment: Try [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/);

Comment: I know requirejs. But It's works for angular dependencies? I want to user for loading http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/

Comment: My problem is that every load of GoogleMapsAPI (https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#maps-credits) is count as a credit. So I only want to load the dependecy when it's needed.

Comment: If the directive isn't used then API isn't used too, is it?

Comment: I'm not talking about a directive, but a module.